# Strange behavior of RandomVariate for Binomial distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

Observe:

```
TableForm@
 Map[{First[Timing[RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[10 #, 1/#]]]],
      First[Timing[RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[10 #, 1/(# + 1)]]]]} &,
  {1500, 3000, 5000, 10000}]

0.          0.733205
0.          1.809612
0.          3.447622
0.          0.
```

Note how the timing goes through the roof simply lowering the probability a tiny amount.

If appears for lowish *n* in `Binomial[n,p]`, when n*p<10, things get strange.

9.01 Windows, would appreciate if others could confirm behavior.

*N.b* - the times above are on my loungebook, so you might need to use this on a real machine to compare - do you see the same drop?:

```
TableForm@
 Map[{First[Timing[Do[RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[10 #, 1/#]], {100}]]],
    First[Timing[Do[RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[10 #, 1/(# + 1)]], {100}]]]} &,
  {1500, 3000, 5000, 10000}]
```

Update: This appears to be caused by heuristics in method switching (hazily outlined in the documentation), probably between a lookup/alias and other methods. This can be seen from:

```
Table[{MaxMemoryUsed[RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[10 x, 1/(x)]]], 
       MaxMemoryUsed[RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[10 x, 1/(x + 1)]]]}, 
    {x, {9999, 10000}}]

(* {{3320, 12630024}, {3200, 2440}} *)
```

Where in this case, x>=10K uses an alternate method.

Comment: ``{0.015625, 0.03125},
{0.`, 0.0625},
{0.`, 0.125},
{0.`, 0.`}}``   Windows 8.1, *Mathematica* 10.0.0.0

Comment: MMA 10.2, Ubuntu, I get `{0.03, 0.1, 0.17, 0.0001}` for the second column

Comment: MMA 10.2, MBP OS 10.10.5, {{0.000292, 0.027283}, {0.000273, 0.058267}, {0.00024, 0.11855}, {0.000227, 0.000081}}

Comment: MMA 9.0.1 kubuntu 14.04, {{0.03036, 4.441168}, {0.020735, 11.5795}, {0.025354, 23.53534}, {0.019794, 0.011695}}

Comment: What if `AbsoluteTiming[]` was used instead?

Comment: No change for me using `AbsoluteTiming`.

Comment: Mine *is* using `AbsoluteTiming[]`, forgot to add

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RandomVariate` for `BinomialDistribution[n,p]` changes between methods depending on the value of `Min[n*{p,1-p}]`. What we're seeing here is that one of those methods is poorly optimized.

Because of this thread, we've made some improvements which should improve speed when `Min[n*{p,1-p}]<10`. These will be in the next release of *Mathematica*. We'll also investigate moving to a better algorithm in the future.

Comment: RandomVariate functionality in general needs a lot of improvement.This is one place where symbolic capabilities are not needed, so if random number generation can be made compilable (at least for few common distributions, e.g., for those in the Rmath library of R), it would be a great help in simulation work.

Comment: Good to hear, thanks for answering.

Comment: @ciao looks fixed in v11

Comment: @blochwave - thanks for the ping!

Answer (score 5):

Please edit with your results:

MMa 11.0.0, Ubuntu - blochwave

```
0.021172    0.019485
0.012286    0.035213
0.012411    0.055937
0.012053    0.005847
```

MMa 10.0.0.0, Windows 8.1 –  Sektor

```
{0.015625, 0.03125}, 
{0.`,      0.0625}, 
{0.`,      0.125}, 
{0.`,      0.`}}
```

MMa 10.0.0.0 through MinGW & mintty, Windows 8.1 –  Sektor

```
{0.,   0.03125}, 
{0.,   0.0625}, 
{0.,   0.125}, 
{0.,   0.}}
```

MMA 10.2, Ubuntu 12.04 - blochwave

```
          {0.03,
           0.1, 
           0.17, 
           0.0001}
```

MMA 10.2, MBP OS 10.10.5, -  Bob Hanlon

```
{{0.000292, 0.027283}, 
{0.000273,  0.058267}, 
{0.00024,   0.11855}, 
{0.000227,  0.000081}}
```

MMA 9.0.1 kubuntu 14.04, - KennyColnago

```
{{0.03036, 4.441168},
 {0.020735, 11.5795}, 
 {0.025354, 23.53534}, 
 {0.019794, 0.011695}}
```

Mma 9.0.1 WinXP, Belisarius

```
{{0.,       0.328125}, 
 {0.,       0.750000},
 {0.,       1.484375}, 
 {0.,       0.}}
```

MMA 10.0.2.0 MBAir OSX 10.10.5 - march

```
0.029516    3.184197
0.024093    8.040635
0.018399    15.686205
0.023200    0.006712
```

MMA 9.0.1.0, MBPro Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013, OS 10.9.5 - heropup

```
{{0.012290, 0.040470},
{0.000434, 0.081408},
{0.000289, 0.162845},
{0.000271, 0.000141}}
```

Comment: Well, interesting. Bug? Or boo-boo algorithmic decision (as in it's switching to something I'd call broken with the suspiciously familiar n*p <10 rule)

Comment: @ciao I would vote for the second option ...

Comment: yep, see update to OP...

Answer (score 5):

I get on Mathematica 10.2, Ubuntu 14.04

```
In[10]:= Map[{First[
    Timing[Do[
      RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[10 #, 1/#]], {100}]]], 
   First[Timing[
     Do[RandomVariate[
       BinomialDistribution[10 #, 1/(# + 1)]], {100}]]]} &, {1500, 
  3000, 5000, 10000}]

Out[10]= {{0.023484, 2.37428}, {0.012502, 6.22335}, {0.013843, 
  12.4218}, {0.012031, 0.005005}}
```

but when I use reals for the probability, we see,

```
In[11]:= Map[{First[
    Timing[Do[
      RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[10 #, 1.0/#]], {100}]]], 
   First[Timing[
     Do[RandomVariate[
       BinomialDistribution[10 #, 1.0/(# + 1.0)]], {100}]]]} &, {1500,
   3000, 5000, 10000}]

Out[11]= {{0.013413, 0.231714}, {0.007382, 0.335648}, {0.007443, 
  0.389959}, {0.006538, 0.003143}}
```